# Audio service package does not display artwork In Android Auto

Tags: android, flutter, android-auto, audio-service

I am making Music app in Flutter. For that, I am using [audio service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) package.
Package displays song artwork for my phone, but It does not display artwork for **Android Auto**.I am using below snippet for broadcasting media item.

```js
MediaItem.add(
id:song.id,
title:song.title,
artUri:Uri.file("/data/user/0/my package name/cache/8744.png")
);
```

Is there any kind of permission needed for Android Auto?

I also tried the android content uri for the same. However, my issue has not been resolved.

Comment: Artwork is static or will change according to different files and devices?

Comment: Yes, It will change according to music files.

Comment: Then why have you added Uri File path statically?

Comment: It is for only example purpose.Uri looks like this.

Comment: How are you getting path dynamically?